# APScheduler Job not running after restart

Tags: python, mongodb, threadpool, jobs, apscheduler

I trying the `MongoJobStore` [example](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/a6545cf29831bb6d8f055aeb2fa9d5204e9bd192/examples/jobstores/mongodb.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) of APS. The example code is:

```
import logging
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

logging.basicConfig()


def alarm(time):
    print('Alarm! This alarm was scheduled at %s.' % time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_jobstore('mongodb', collection='example_jobs', host='192.168.0.108', port=27017)

    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '--clear':
        scheduler.remove_all_jobs()

    alarm_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
    # scheduler.add_job(alarm, 'date', run_date=alarm_time, args=[datetime.now()], id="la")
    print('To clear the alarms, run this example with the --clear argument.')
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    scheduler.start()
```

First to test I ran the code and the output of the `alarm` method got printed on the console. Then to test the use of mongo I did the following:

1. Ran the example and stopped it before executing the job.
2. This created a following entry in the db

   ```
   > db.example_jobs.find().pretty()
   {
       "_id" : "la",
       "next_run_time" : 1456771825.792437,
       "job_state" : BinData(0,"gAJ9cQEoVQRhcmdzcQJjZGF0ZXRpbWUKZGF0ZXRpbWUKcQNVCgfgAwEAFA8MF4SFUnEEhXEFVQhleGVjdXRvcnEGVQdkZWZhdWx0cQdVDW1heF9pbnN0YW5jZXNxCEsBVQRmdW5jcQlVDl9fbWFpbl9fOmFsYXJtcQpVAmlkcQtVAmxhcQxVDW5leHRfcnVuX3RpbWVxDWgDVQoH4AMBABQZDBd1Y3B5dHoKX3AKcQ4oVQxBc2lhL0tvbGthdGFxD01YTUsAVQNJU1RxEHRScRGGUnESVQRuYW1lcRNVBWFsYXJtcRRVEm1pc2ZpcmVfZ3JhY2VfdGltZXEVSwFVB3RyaWdnZXJxFmNhcHNjaGVkdWxlci50cmlnZ2Vycy5kYXRlCkRhdGVUcmlnZ2VyCnEXKYFxGH1xGX1xGlUIcnVuX2RhdGVxG2gSc4ZiVQhjb2FsZXNjZXEciFUHdmVyc2lvbnEdSwFVBmt3YXJnc3EefXEfdS4=")
   }
   ```
3. Then I commented the line which was adding the job: `# scheduler.add_job(alarm, 'date', run_date=alarm_time, args=[datetime.now()], id="la")`
4. Then I ran the script again and got following output:

   ```
   To clear the alarms, run this example with the --clear argument.
   Press Ctrl+C to exit
   WARNING:apscheduler.executors.default:Run time of job "alarm (trigger: date[2016-03-01 00:35:27 IST], next run at: 2016-03-01 00:35:27 IST)" was missed by 0:00:19.290825
   ```
5. The output of the `alarm` function is not printed and the record is deleted from the db.

I tried debugging the second run, the code is reading the job from the db and then submitting it to the `threadpool`. But no output is printed.

Why this could be happening?

Comment: May I ask that how did you set the default logger? I cannot figure out and always prompts message like 'cannot find logger apscheduler.executors.default'.

Answer (score 6):

The issue was `misfire_grace_time` ([doc](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#missed-job-executions-and-coalescing)). I didn't set it. It was actually not set even in the example itself.

Working code:

```
import logging
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

logging.basicConfig()


def alarm(time):
    print('Alarm! This alarm was scheduled at %s.' % time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_jobstore('mongodb', collection='example_jobs', host='192.168.0.108', port=27017)

    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '--clear':
        scheduler.remove_all_jobs()

    alarm_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
    scheduler.add_job(alarm, 'date', run_date=alarm_time, args=[datetime.now()], id="la", misfire_grace_time=1000)
    print('To clear the alarms, run this example with the --clear argument.')
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    scheduler.start()
```

I got this answer from APS's IRC channel `#apscheduler`. `@agronholm` helped me.